# Trying to read data from firebase second node after reading first node

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to read firebase data from second node as soon as data reading from first node complete and displaying it into recyclerview.
as for example Im trying to read data from Question node in which I stored Id of an user when question node read succesfully i use id value to read second node but i'm not getting value properly i.e second node not reading completely.

```
firebaseDatabase.getReference().child("QnA").child("Answers").child(pushkey).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

        for (DataSnapshot snapshot1: snapshot.getChildren()) {
            for (DataSnapshot snapshot2: snapshot1.getChildren()) {
                Answername = snapshot2.child("Answer").getValue(String.class);
                currenttime = snapshot2.child("Answer_time").getValue(String.class);
                new_name = snapshot2.child("answer_name").getValue(String.class);

                * database_scholar_id * = snapshot2.child("Scholar_id").getValue(String.class);

                System.out.println("Reading daat from firebase id");
                System.out.println(database_scholar_id);

                System.out.println("Scholar id read from datbase");
                System.out.println(database_scholar_id);

                String[] newData = new String[] {
                    Answername,
                    currenttime,
                    new_name,
                    user_ka_profile
                };

                firebaseDatabase.getReference().child("users").child(database_scholar_id).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                        String user__name = "";
                        for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot: snapshot.getChildren()) {

                            user__name = dataSnapshot.child("user__name").getValue(String.class);
                            System.out.println("Reading bio");
                            System.out.println(user__name);

                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                    }
                });

                data.add(0, newData);

                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }

        mAdapter.notifyItemInserted(0);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
    }
});
```

Here is the DB structure:

```
{
  "QnA": {
    "Answers": {
        "-NOsBtK2IgL0O1MzM7D9": {
          "11111513456": {
            "Answer": "kisne kiya ms",
            "Answer_time": "22 Feb 23",
            "Scholar_id": "11111513456",
            "answer_name": "remobro"
          }
        }
      },
      "-NODnFnoMery1jVLHW9u": {
        "-NOsERiEDmE-5W0utC3a": {
          "11111513456": {
            "Answer": "Hello this is",
            "Answer_time": "22 Feb 23",
            "Scholar_id": "11111513456",
            "answer_name": "Som"
          }
        },
        "-NOsEmdgvX2PdsW_YhRs": {
          "11111513456": {
            "Answer": "Hello this is Me!",
            "Answer_time": "22 Feb 23",
            "Scholar_id": "11111513710",
            "answer_name": "Remo"
          }
        },
        "-NOsFRnqKeic9qu0UCMD": {
          "11111513456": {
            "Answer": "Hello this is Me!",
            "Answer_time": "22 Feb 23",
            "Scholar_id": "11111513456",
            "answer_name": "SomeOne"
          }
        }
      },
      "-NOpOEGtREVOjMaBB4E_": {
        "-NOpPMWdLeaerNhgyZmU": {
          " 11111513710": {
            "Answer": "I guess Yes",
            "Answer_time": "21 Feb 23",
            "Scholar_id": " 11111513710",
            "answer_name": "remobro"
          }
        },
        "-NOpPO6uQklj_z7rRJ05": {
          " 11111513710": {
            "Answer": "I don't Know ",
            "Answer_time": "21 Feb 23",
            "Scholar_id": " 11111513710",
            "answer_name": "remobro"
          }
        },
        "-NOpQEG7gCPFyN4xYSqE": {
          " 11111513710": {
            "Answer": "Hello this is Me!",
            "Answer_time": "21 Feb 23",
            "Scholar_id": " 11111513710",
            "answer_name": "remobro"
          }
        },
        "-NOpQZVNzpbF8rHm1TMw": {
          " 11111513710": {
            "Answer": "Hello this is",
            "Answer_time": "21 Feb 23",
            "Scholar_id": " 11111513710",
            "answer_name": "remobro"
          }
        },
        "-NOpQiAEf1g8wRZstQGh": {
          " 11111513710": {
            "Answer": "Hello this",
            "Answer_time": "21 Feb 23",
            "Scholar_id": " 11111513710",
            "answer_name": "remobro"
          }
        },
        "-NOsAJOJ_qOdnp7fYFi1": {
          "11111513456": {
            "Answer": "Hello this is Me!",
            "Answer_time": "22 Feb 23",
            "Scholar_id": "11111513710",
            "answer_name": "remobro"
          }
        },
        "-NOsE4tKkLbKZu1Volka": {
          "11111513456": {
            "Answer": "Hello",
            "Answer_time": "22 Feb 23",
            "Scholar_id": "11111513456",
            "answer_name": "SomeOne"
          }
        },
        "-NOsE6e2Rqz8xkWUa2Fp": {
          "11111513456": {
            "Answer": "Hell",
            "Answer_time": "22 Feb 23",
            "Scholar_id": "11111513456",
            "answer_name": "SomeOne"
          }
        }
      },
      "-NOpUpxz2pjjAO_M-ICb": {
        "-NOs6t50zdL7kXEaadzY": {
          "11111513456": {
            "Answer": "Hello t",
            "Answer_time": "22 Feb 23",
            "Scholar_id": "11111513456",
            "answer_name": "SomeOne"
          }
        },
        "-NOs9lO8g4e3Pr8SN33L": {
          "11111513456": {
            "Answer": "Hello this is Me!",
            "Answer_time": "22 Feb 23",
            "Scholar_id": "11111513456",
            "answer_name": "SomeOne"
          }
        }
      },
      "-NOwjqMSTyj3n99suf_P": {
        "-NOwjtvHy0Lo8pfXXRoC": {
          "11111513456": {
            "Answer": "Heeyyy Broo...",
            "Answer_time": "23 Feb 23",
            "Scholar_id": "11111513456",
            "answer_name": "SomeOne"
          }
        },
        "-NOwk1urC4efe3HXgHPM": {
          "11111513456": {
            "Answer": "Heeyyy Bro",
            "Answer_time": "23 Feb 23",
            "Scholar_id": "11111513710",
            "answer_name": "SomeOne"
          }
        },
        "-NOwu9XBJXT220gHNbY0": {
          "11111513456": {
            "Answer": "Hello this is Me!",
            "Answer_time": "23 Feb 23",
            "Scholar_id": "11111513710",
            "answer_name": "SomeOne"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "Questions": {
      "-NODVvgMGy_UqdZnxf_U": {
        "category_qna_asked": "Java",
        "downvote": "0",
        "pushkey": "-NODVvgMGy_UqdZnxf_U",
        "qna_timestamp_asked": "15 Feb 23",
        "question_qna_asked": "Is java Great??",
        "scholar_id": " 11111513711",
        "upvote": "0",
        "user_qna_name_asked": "remobro"
      },
      "-NODnFnoMery1jVLHW9u": {
        "Answers": {
          "-NOiakLiGftWTh8OnwSD": {
            " 11111513710": {
              "Answer": "Hello thie!",
              "Answer_time": "20 Feb 23",
              "Scholar_id": " 11111513710"
            }
          }
        },
        "category_qna_asked": "Kotlin",
        "downvote": "0",
        "pushkey": "-NODnFnoMery1jVLHW9u",
        "qna_timestamp_asked": "14 Feb 23",
        "question_qna_asked": "wow",
        "scholar_id": " 11111513710",
        "upvote": "0",
        "user_qna_name_asked": "remo"
      },
      "-NOpOEGtREVOjMaBB4E_": {
        "category_qna_asked": "Python",
        "downvote": "0",
        "pushkey": "-NOpOEGtREVOjMaBB4E_",
        "qna_timestamp_asked": "21 Feb 23",
        "question_qna_asked": "Is python overrated???",
        "scholar_id": " 11111513710",
        "upvote": "0",
        "user_qna_name_asked": "remobro"
      },
      "-NOpUpxz2pjjAO_M-ICb": {
        "category_qna_asked": "CPP",
        "downvote": "0",
        "pushkey": "-NOpUpxz2pjjAO_M-ICb",
        "qna_timestamp_asked": "21 Feb 23",
        "question_qna_asked": "What the Hell??",
        "scholar_id": "11111513456",
        "upvote": "0",
        "user_qna_name_asked": "SomeOne"
      },
      "-NOwjqMSTyj3n99suf_P": {
        "category_qna_asked": "Kotlin",
        "downvote": "0",
        "pushkey": "-NOwjqMSTyj3n99suf_P",
        "qna_timestamp_asked": "23 Feb 23",
        "question_qna_asked": "Hello Brother...",
        "scholar_id": "11111513456",
        "upvote": "0",
        "user_qna_name_asked": "SomeOne"
      }
    }
  },
  "users": {
    " 11111513710": {
      "profiles": {
        "Bio": "Something ",
        "Followers": 0,
        "Following": 0,
        "Github_url": "",
        "LinkedIn_url": "",
        "image": "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885__480.jpg",
        "user__name": "Remo"
      }
    },
    "11111513456": {
      "profiles": {
        "Bio": "This is My Bio.",
        "Followers": 0,
        "Following": 0,
        "Github_url": "",
        "LinkedIn_url": "",
        "image": "https://www.shutterstock.com/image-photo/surreal-image-african-elephant-wearing-260nw-1365289022.jpg",
        "user__name": "SomeOne"
      }
    },
    "emkfQD2ORLfPE44ykkMNPPJ5NM13": {
      "questions_asked": {
        "-NOsmWyZGCk2FUovXdW4": {
          "my_question": "What can I ask ???",
          "question_id": "-NOsmWyYfUlRH7DZ1I2I",
          "question_time": "22 Feb 23"
        },
        "-NOwjjZ9_mKq8ABwSAIy": {
          "my_question": "Hello Brother...",
          "question_id": "-NOwjjZ9_mKq8ABwSAIx",
          "question_time": "23 Feb 23"
        },
        "-NOwjqT0gbjRpyr4ROcA": {
          "my_question": "Hello Brother...",
          "question_id": "-NOwjqT-Qn7LQNrMzneW",
          "question_time": "23 Feb 23"
        }
      }
    }
  }
This is my database structure
```

This is code which i tried to retrive information from different node..

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/data).

Comment: I added my firebase database structure

Comment: What is the value of `pushkey` inside your reference and what exactly would you like to get from that query?

Comment: pushkey value is Questions id, whenever  user clicks on any question and try to asnwer of that question than all that answer stored inside of that Question id in Answer node

Comment: And what exactly would you like to get from that query?

Comment: well im trying to read value of image from user node of that user who answer question. So when data load in recyclyclerview  from Answers node there is scholarid to which I used to load image from user node and displaying it inside of recycyclerview.